# join 3 table in codeigniter with null value in table

Tags: codeigniter

I want data from 3 table and  in fee pericualr field batch id and student id may be blank if i use join then empty query is showing.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('fees_perticular');
$this->db->join('fee_cat', 'fees_perticular.fee_cat = fee_cat.id');
$this->db->join('batch', 'fees_perticular.batch= batch.id');
$this->db->join('stud_cat', 'fees_perticular.sud_cat = stud_cat.id');

$query = $this->db->get();
id |    fee_cat |   particular_name |   desc     |all |batch|admission|sud_cat|amount
1  |    1       |     Annual Fees   |Annual Fees |all |-    |-        |-      |2000
2  |    2       |     Tuition Fees  |Tuition Fees|-   |3    |-        |-      |1000
3  |    1       |     Tuition Fees  |vccvv       |-   |1    |-        |-      |1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$this->db->select('*')
$this->db->join('fee_cat','fees_particular.fee_cat=fee_cat.fee_cat_id','LEFT')
$this->db->join('batch','fees_particular.batch=batch.batch_id','LEFT')
$this->db->join('stud_cat','fees_particular.stud_cat=stud_cat.stud_cat_id','LEFT')
$this->db->get('fees_particular');
```

Comment: I have tried this but sud_cat is empty thats why empty query is resulted due to join

Comment: Logically the output is correct. What you are doing is joining with ID's which should be equal in all tables. In case of failure of any of the logic in 3 joins, your whole logic will result in FALSE (No data will be retrieved)

Comment: Thanx ID was mismatching in 2 table so it was not resulting correct answer